# Sending Id's of Selected rows to controller from Data Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, datatables

I am using datatable and want to send multiple id's to controller

```
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                "sRowSelect": "multi"
            }
        } );

        var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance( 'example' );
        var aSelectedTrs = oTT.fnGetSelected();
       //Needs an Ajax function to send aSelectedTrs to controller
 $('#button').click(function () {
                alert(aSelectedTrs);
            });
    } );
```

When I try to alert the value of seleted rows. Its null .....Other problem is I want to only send first column as an array(how many user selects) to controller.

I tried another way like

```
var aReturn = new Array();
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();  
        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
           var rowData =table.row(this).data();
            aReturn.push(rowData);
           // alert(aReturn);
        });
```

It shows the array here but when I try to get the values on button click

```
 $('#button').click(function () {
                    alert(aReturn);
                });
        } );
```

It shows null...

I need to send this array to controller via Ajax plz...Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Do you have any error in browser console

Comment: No errors in browser....I donno the way to pass the rows to controller ....When I display the array within the click function of body ...values are being displayed but how to access it from button click method OR post it direct to controller